# AMP-Story does not allow me to add more than 15 pages

Tags: html, css, amp-html, google-amp, amp-stories

I've been playing around with AMP-stories the last few days and I started working on a project with them  but I run into an issue. After:

```
<amp-story-page id="page15">
```

The following pages are not visible. Yes the files work. They work in the previous pages but not after id=page15.

```
    <!-- Page 16 -->
      <amp-story-page id="page15">
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="vertical">
          <amp-video src="assets/ig/converted/1.mp4"
              width="720" height="1280"
              layout="responsive">
          </amp-video>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
      </amp-story-page>

      <!-- Page 17 -->
      <amp-story-page id="page16">
        <amp-story-grid-layer template="vertical">
          <amp-video src="assets/ig/converted/2.mp4"
              width="720" height="1280"
              layout="responsive">
          </amp-video>
        </amp-story-grid-layer>
       </amp-story-page>
```

I'm using all video files for my stories.

I could not find any information in the docs or the slack community of AMP.

Notes:

- I did check my page numbering multiple times. everything is numbered properly from cover to page1 to page15 etc.
- My videos work before id=page15 but not after
- All videos are VALID, mp4 and work on page 15 and down.

I get the following error once I reach story 16:

```
Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
```

Does anyone else have the same problem and/or solution to this?

Comment: This amp story has over 30 pages so probably there is no limit about that: https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/2018/national/amp-stories/border-wall/

Comment: It seems that you cannot use more than 15 videos in one story. Try to remove one of the previous videos and you will see that the video number 16 will be played

Comment: How to turn off black screen before site loads "You must enable the amp-story experiment to view this content"

Comment: I believe this is a bug: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/12865